# Joda Time: How to get dates of weekdays on some date interval?

Tags: java, datetime, date, jodatime

I have two LocalDates that represent some time interval. Now i have to get LocalDates of all fridays, that this interval contains.
Easiest way to do it?

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: lazily step by one week.

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class DayOfWeekIterator implements Iterator<LocalDate>{
    private final LocalDate end;
    private LocalDate nextDate;

    public DayOfWeekIterator(LocalDate start, LocalDate end, int dayOfWeekToIterate){
        this.end = end;
        nextDate = start.withDayOfWeek(dayOfWeekToIterate);
        if (start.getDayOfWeek() > dayOfWeekToIterate) {
            nextDate = nextDate.plusWeeks(1);
        }
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return !nextDate.isAfter(end);
    }

    public LocalDate next() {
        LocalDate result = nextDate;
        nextDate = nextDate.plusWeeks(1);
        return result;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
 }
```

Test

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public class DayOfWeekIteratorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LocalDate startDate = new LocalDate(2010, 12, 1);//1st Dec 2010
        LocalDate endDate = new LocalDate(2010, 12, 31);//31st Dec 2010
        DayOfWeekIterator it = new DayOfWeekIterator(startDate, endDate, DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY);
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
package org.life.java.so.questions;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants;

/**
 *
 * @author Jigar
 */
public class JodaTimeDateTraverseQuestion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateTime startDt = new DateTime(2010,12,1,0,0,0,0);//1st Dec 2010
        DateTime endDt = new DateTime(2010,12,31,0,0,0,0);//31st Dec 2010
        DateTime tempDate = new DateTime(startDt.getMillis());
        while(tempDate.compareTo(endDt) <=0 ){
            if(tempDate.getDayOfWeek() !=  DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY && tempDate.getDayOfWeek() !=  DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY){
                System.out.println(""+tempDate);
            }
            tempDate = tempDate.plusDays(1);

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 )  // A date-only class in the modern *java.time* classes that supplant both Joda-Time and the troublesome old date-time classes.
    .with(  
        TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY )   // Nifty `TemporalAdjuster` implementation for moving to another date. Immutable Objects pattern means a new object is returned based on the original which remains unmodified.
    )
    .isBefore(                                       // Compare `LocalDate` objects with `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `isEqual`. 
        LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 27 );
    )
```

## java.time

FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Define your stop & start `LocalDate` objects.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 27 );
// TODO: Verify start.isBefore( stop ).
```

Collect the Friday dates we find. You might optimize a bit by sizing the collection.

```
// Pre-size the collection.
int initialCapacity = ( int ) ( ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between( start , stop ) + 2 ); // Adding two for good measure.
List < LocalDate > fridays = new ArrayList <>( initialCapacity );
```

Determine the first Friday, using the start date if it is itself a Friday. Use a pair of [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementations offered in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class: [`next​(DayOfWeek)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#next-java.time.DayOfWeek-) & [`nextOrSame​(DayOfWeek)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#nextOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-). Pass the desired day-of-week via the `DayOfWeek` enum, seven pre-defined objects, one for each day of the week Monday-Sunday.

```
LocalDate friday = start.with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY ) );

while ( friday.isBefore( stop ) )
{
    fridays.add( friday );  // Remember this Friday date.
    // Setup next loop.
    friday = friday.with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY ) );
}

System.out.println( "From " + start + " to " + stop + " = " + fridays );
```

> From 2018-01-23 to 2018-02-27 = [2018-01-26, 2018-02-02, 2018-02-09, 2018-02-16, 2018-02-23]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).