# Joda time - all mondays between two dates

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, days

I am using Joda time api in a Spring 3.0 project for the very first time. Now I have a start and end date and I want to get the date for all mondays between these two dates. How can I do this ?

I have no idea where to start, can someone please advise. I looked at theis post [Joda Time: How to get dates of weekdays on some date interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547768/joda-time-how-to-get-dates-of-weekdays-on-some-date-interval) and it offered some sort of guidance but its still somewhat vague due to little experience with joda.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
LocalDate startDate = new LocalDate(2011, 11, 8);
LocalDate endDate = new LocalDate(2012, 5, 1);

LocalDate thisMonday = startDate.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);

if (startDate.isAfter(thisMonday)) {
    startDate = thisMonday.plusWeeks(1); // start on next monday
} else {
    startDate = thisMonday; // start on this monday
}

while (startDate.isBefore(endDate)) {
    System.out.println(startDate);
    startDate = startDate.plusWeeks(1);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to calculate all days between a start and end date but skipping weekend or probably skipping saturday or sunday?

Answer (score 5):

I recently developed [Lamma](http://lamma.io) which is designed to solve this exact use case:

```
Dates.from(2011, 11, 8).to(2011, 12, 30).byWeek().on(DayOfWeek.MONDAY).build();
```

and you will get a `List<Date>` of:

```
Date(2011,11,14)
Date(2011,11,21)
Date(2011,11,28)
Date(2011,12,5)
Date(2011,12,12)
Date(2011,12,19)
Date(2011,12,26)
```

Answer (score 4):

FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## Using java.time

The `LocalDate` class is java.time is akin to the Joda-Time `LocalDate`. A date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone. One difference is that java.time eschews constructors for factory methods.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2011 , 11 , 8 );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2012 , 5 , 1 );
```

Collect the Mondays.

```
List<LocalDate> mondays = new ArrayList<>();
```

The [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface provides for classes that manipulate date-time values. The [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class (note the plural name) provides various implementations. We want the [`nextOrSame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#nextOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-) and [`next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#next-java.time.DayOfWeek-) adjusters, passing the desired [`DayOfWeek.MONDAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#MONDAY) enum object.

```
LocalDate monday = start.with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) );
while( monday.isBefore( stop ) ) {
    mondays.add( monday );
    // Set up the next loop.
    monday = monday.plusWeeks( 1 );
}
```

By the way, usually the wise approach in handling a span of time is Half-Open where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So in the code above we are running up to, but not including, the `stop` date.

If the ending is *inclusive*, use the negation of [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-) e.g.

```
while( !monday.isAfter( stop ) ) {
    //...
}
```

Here, `monday` is not after `stop` means it is before or up to `stop`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2):

This code takes to string dates and gives the number of sundays and also all the sunday's dates

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class FindAllSundays {


public static int getNumberofSundays(String d1, String d2) throws Exception { // object
                                                                                // in
                                                                                // Date
                                                                                // form

    Date date1 = getDate(d1);
    Date date2 = getDate(d2);

    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(date1);
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.setTime(date2);
    int sundays = 0;
    while (c2.after(c1)) {
        // System.out.println(" came here ");
        //checks to see if the day1 ....so on next days are sundays if sunday goes inside to increment the counter
        if (c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            System.out.println(c1.getTime().toString() + " is a sunday ");
            sundays++;

        }
        c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    System.out.println("number of sundays between 2 dates is " + sundays);

    return sundays;
}
// converts string to date 
public static Date getDate(String s) {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = format.parse(s);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}

public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(" " + getNumberofSundays("2005-10-07", "2006-10-01"));
}
```

}

Comment: Some explanation to the Code for OP would be nice

Comment: being the 1st post i still didn't get the hang of will change accordingly

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Get_time {

    public  ArrayList<LocalDate> getmondays(String s,String e)
    {
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse(s);
        LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse(e);
        List<LocalDate> totalDates_Mondays = new ArrayList<>();

        while (!start.isAfter(end)) {
            totalDates_Mondays.add(start);
            start = start.plusWeeks(1);
        }
        return (ArrayList<LocalDate>) totalDates_Mondays;
    }

    public static void main(String ...s1) {

        String mon_start = "1600-08-01";
        String mon_end= "2016-12-29";
        Get_time t=new Get_time();
        System.out.println(t.getmondays(mon_start,mon_end));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 using Stream ,

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2019, 2, 1);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2019, 2, 28);
long numOfDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
List<LocalDate> daysRange = Stream.iterate(startDate, date -> date.plusDays(1)).limit(numOfDays).filter( date -> date.getDayOfWeek()==DayOfWeek.MONDAY ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```