# DateRange iterating wrong (code taken from SO)

Tags: java, spring-boot, iteration, localdate

A few months ago I found this thread about iterating over days in java

[Java 8 LocalDate - How do I get all dates between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220543/java-8-localdate-how-do-i-get-all-dates-between-two-dates)

And started using class DateRange:

```
public class DateRange implements Iterable<LocalDate> {

    private final LocalDate startDate;
    private final LocalDate endDate;

    public DateRange(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
        //check that range is valid (null, start < end)
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<LocalDate> iterator() {
        return stream().iterator();
    }

    public Stream<LocalDate> stream() {
        return Stream.iterate(startDate, d -> d.plusDays(1))
                .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate) + 1);
    }

    public List<LocalDate> toList() { //could also be built from the stream() method
        List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (LocalDate d = startDate; !d.isAfter(endDate); d = d.plusDays(1)) {
            dates.add(d);
        }
        return dates;
    }

}
```

Either way, today while debugging I found out that this is not working at all, I was wondering how iterating over a week took so long. Just to find out that it was iterating same days multiple times in random order.

Problem is probably me not understanding how to use this...

```
    for (LocalDate date : new DateRange(thymeDate.getDate_a(), thymeDate.getDate_b())) {

        List<Group_C> owners = getAllByDate(date);
        groupList = composeGroup.composeGroupForRange(groupList, owners);

    }
    return GroupList;
}
```

I've also tried `DateRange.between()` as in the example, which is not a function, so can't be used?
and creating the new normal instance.

`DateRange range = new DateRange(dateA, dateB)`

and `@Autowire`ing DateRange class.

How would I iterate over given days?

[image: timeline in SysOut]

Comment: Can you use Java 9? There’s a new `datesUntil` method that will be convenient for your task.

Comment: Perhaps, but im kind of disliking the idea of switching SDK in the middle of this just because i cant get one class to work.

Comment: Your code works nicely for me. I couldn’t test with `thymeDate`, `getAllByDate` and `composeGroup`, of course, because you haven’t provided those. I think your problem may be in one of those or in yet a third place. [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: thymeDate only has properties dateA and dateB, i also get right values 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1 but then it will use 2.1 as date again, and then 3.1. getByDate simply retrieves entities for that date. Anything besides this for loop should not interact with date.

Comment: i understood that, but still cant understand how that's possible. this is the only code for the loop. This code is standalone,  and what i get is totally random order of dates, sometimes multiple of same date. Using JDK 8 and spring boot.

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn’t run in two threads in parallel? Every date comes exactly twice in your output, so this would explain very nicely.

Comment: Yeah, i just found out for some reason my controller is called twice... and now i cant figure where thats coming from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was ultimately a problem with double `POST`,caused by using proxy. DateRange method was fine all along...
You can see solution for double `POST` problem in another thread
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595364/react-axios-double-post-request-to-spring-restcontroller-also-in-fetch-seem)

Thanks to Ole V.V. for trying to help :)