# Current month count monday?

Tags: java

**How do you find the total number of Mondays (e.g. 4 or 5) in a particular month ???**

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mon = c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

is this right way ??

Comment: What does that mean? Do you want the number of Mondays in the current month? (so 4 or 5)?

Comment: Yes.I want total number of monday in current month.

Comment: Try it. Do you think [this month has 11 mondays](http://ideone.com/fMzwag)?

Comment: No.How is this possible that current month having 11 Monday. The ans should be 4 or 5..

Comment: @user3852778 So, is it the right way?

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong. I am not getting how to do it.Can You help me to solve this issue by giving me example or tutorials...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040790/joda-time-all-mondays-between-two-dates

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7651306/2764279)

Comment: Locate first Monday in month, (You can check which day of week was at 1st of that month using `c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`). Increment your counter while adding 7 days to this Monday until you get date in next month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this method

```
public int countMonday(int year, int month) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Note that month is 0-based in calendar, bizarrely.
    calendar.set(year, month - 1, 1);
    int daysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    int count = 0;
    for (int day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++) {
        calendar.set(year, month - 1, day);
        int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.MONDAY) {
            count++;
            // Or do whatever you need to with the result.
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

**Updated**

```
public int countDayOccurence(int year, int month,int dayToFindCount) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Note that month is 0-based in calendar, bizarrely.
    calendar.set(year, month - 1, 1);
    int daysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    int count = 0;
    for (int day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++) {
        calendar.set(year, month - 1, day);
        int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (dayOfWeek == dayToFindCount) {
            count++;
            // Or do whatever you need to with the result.
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

And then you can call this method for each day name

```
   int countMonday = countDayOccurence(year,month,Calendar.MONDAY);
   int countTuesday = countDayOccurence(year,month,Calendar.TUESDAY);
```

...............................................

Comment: and what about mon to sun each and separately count ??

Comment: what do you mean by fully?

Comment: If that is working dont forget to mark that as answer or up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Calendar api, the best option I can see is to:

1. get the actual maximum day of month (i.e. how many days in this month)
2. set calendar to first day of the month and get the day of the week
3. calculate how many mondays could occur (i.e. if 28 days in month - 4, if 29 4 unless month started on a monday, if 30, 4 unless month started on monday or tuesday, if 31, 4 unless started on monday, tuesday, or wednesday).

Comment: july 2013 we have 5 Mondays

Comment: right and july 2013 had 31 days and july 1 2013 was a monday. thus following the rules i laid out

Comment: if 31, 4 unless started on monday, tuesday, or wednesday , what do you mean by this

Comment: If there are 31 days in the month, then there are 4 mondays unless the first day of the month was a monday, tuesday or wednesday.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need at least for the current month :

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();        
    int maxDaysInMonth = c.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int firstMonday = c.get(Calendar.MONDAY); // first monday in the month (Beware, 0 is the first day of the month)
    int mondays = 0;
    int i=firstMonday;
    while(i<maxDaysInMonth){
        mondays++;
        i+=7;
    };
    System.out.println(mondays);
```

Comment: I'm asking you what error do you get. Describe it please.

Comment: Listening on javadebug
Not able to submit breakpoint LineBreakpoint Customer_Bills.java : 11, reason: The breakpoint is set outside of any class.
Invalid LineBreakpoint Customer_Bills.java : 11
User program running
User program finished

Comment: Not so hard you see ? You must have a breakpoint somewhere. Just remove it. It has nothing to do with the while loop which has nothing special

Comment: But if i want for others days also in same code then how to code ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my question.

@Ramzan Zafar:
Answer is right and more in that i created my calender instance for current year and month for year and month.
I got my answer as per my question.