# Number of days between two joda dates including holidays

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to get the difference between two joda dates objects. I know how to calculate the difference between two dates using the below code:

```
Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate)
```

I need to calculate the difference in business days where I want to exclude weekends and holidays. Is there is way for the same?

Comment: No silver bullet solution for holidays, as they vary by country & industry & business & department. You'll need to find a data feed for your holidays or define your own data.

Answer (score 3):

Consider these for the number of weekdays

[Joda Time: How to get dates of weekdays on some date interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547768/joda-time-how-to-get-dates-of-weekdays-on-some-date-interval)

[Calculate number of weekdays between two dates in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600034/calculate-number-of-weekdays-between-two-dates-in-java)

As to holidays these are specific to your locale. A Set populated by a config file containing dates should suffice.